# Visualization: best approach?

Tags: iphone, ios, visualization, visualizer

I need to visualize stuff and want to ask for some hints and tutorials. Or which technique to use (Cocos2D, OpenGL, Quartz, ...)

Anyone here who did Visualization on iOS Devices?

It's about moving objects, fading, particles and more...

Any help is appreciated. I attached two examples.

[image: example 1] [image: example 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you what to present.  For something like the very organic color blobs on the left, OpenGL is probably the way to go.  For something more crisp and regular like the chart of the right, CoreAnimation layers are probably a good approach because they would be easy to work with yet also performant.

OpenGL does take more work to understand but of course in the end is going to offer the most flexibility, so it's more a matter of deciding how far down the graphics rabbit hole you really want to go.